# docker-compose stop working after Docker Desktop installation on Debian 11

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, debian, docker-desktop

I installed Docker Desktop for Linux on my Debian 11 machine.

After the installation, I'm not able to use docker-compose or laravel sail.
The error is:

```bash
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

The DOCKER_HOST env variable is not set.

The docker CLI is still working properly.

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Fastest and cleaner way:

Check *"Enable Docker Compose V1/V2 compatibility mode"* in the *General* section of the Docker Desktop settings.

**TLDR:**

1. Run the command `docker context ls` to discover the new host.
2. Copy the *DOCKER ENDPOINT* corresponding to the *desktop-Linux* context
3. Set the *DOCKER_HOST* environment variable by choosing one of those two methods:

   - Open a terminal and execute `export DOCKER_HOST={your docker endpoint}` (this is valid only for the current terminal session and you will lose the config on system reboot)
   - Follow those [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) to set a permanent environment variable (you have to use *DOCKER_HOST* as a variable name and your own *DOCKER ENDPOINT* as a value, not the ones used as an example in the answer)

**Long answer and explanation:**

The *Docker Desktop on Linux* [runs on a virtual machine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/#why-docker-desktop-for-linux-runs-a-vm) and uses *docker compose V2* instead of `docker-compose` (the command to use it is `docker compose` without the hyphen).

To avoid  it masks the docker engine service on the local machine and creates a new [context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/).

As the local *Docker* service has been masked, it is not running anymore on your local machine.

The [context can be switched](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/#context) to the default one if you want to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop. That way your local docker-compose will work as before.

Another way is to connect the local *docker-compose* to the *Docker Desktop* host on the new virtual machine.

This can be done in two ways:

1. By using an environment variable, as explained above in the **TLDR** section.
2. By passing the host address to the *docker-compose* command: `docker-compose -H {your docker endpoint} COMMAND`

Answer (score 0):

1. `docker context ls`
   give output

```
DOCKER ENDPOINT: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

2. 

```
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

3. then give

```
docker-compose up -d
```

it will work