# Docker not working anymore in Ubuntu after installing Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

I installed Docker Desktop in Xubuntu 22.04, and now, if I try to do `docker compose up` or `docker build`, I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/dario/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I already tried `systemctl enable docker` and `systemctl start docker`, indeed `systemctl status docker` output is:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-10 11:42:12 CEST; 1min 56s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1671 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 12
     Memory: 125.7M
        CPU: 433ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1671 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/cont>
```

Even if I stop docker with `systemctl stop docker` and run it with `dockerd` instead, I got the same problem. Also file ownership is ok and my user is in `docker` group. Docker is at the last version and is installed by snap. I really can't get what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally understood what was wrong.

I realized that most tutorials told me to try and change permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock`, meaning that by default docker points to this file.

But my `docker` output was: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/dario/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`.

So I guessed that maybe `docker.service` daemon was still pointing to the first one, while `docker` command was looking for the latter

So I edited `/etc/init/docker.conf` and `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` by following [this guide](https://geekflare.com/change-docker-sock-file-path/#:%7E:text=Edit%20docker.&text=Edit%20the%20docker.,one%20line%20with%20DOCKER_SOCKET%20path.) and just replaced, in each file, `/var/run/docker.sock` with `/home/dario/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`

My guess was right and now Docker works like charm!

EDIT:

I had to reinstall my OS and this error came out again. The solution I explained was not sufficent anymore, and I had to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388122/docker-compose-stop-working-after-docker-desktop-installation-on-debian-11) to get it fixed.

EDIT #2:

Actually, using `docker-compose -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock  mycontainer` worked, but it is a bit too verbose and the instruction to make it permanent did not work for me.

Now I found another quick fix. Look at the output of `docker context ls`, which in my case is:

```
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                  KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                            swarm
desktop-linux *     moby                                                          unix:///home/dario/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

The asterisk after `desktop-linux` means it is the current Docker context which is being used. In my case, switching to `default` does the job.

It is not a neat solution, but I made my PC run `docker context use default` at boot time and now everything works fine.

Comment: this is insightful, but it still doesn't work for me, I exactly had the same problem with you. The only difference is that I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 Jellyfish, and the error message appears in `docker version` after launching Docker Desktop.

Comment: I jsut updated my answer, remanding to another one which I found useful after I faced this problem once again and my previous solution did not work.